# having trouble installing a perl script

Tags: cpanel

I am having trouble installing a perl script. I have upload it to the correct directory, when I say to install it by name I get the following error:

```
Bad module name (ultravnc_repeater.pl) detected, skipping it.
```

Any ideas?

I also get the following error:

```
There was a problem fetching the list of available modules.
```

Even when I say to install it by name I get the following error

```
Testing connection speed...(using fast method)...Done 
Ping:3 (ticks) Testing connection speed to cpan.mirror.clemson.edu using pureperl...(15025.00 bytes/s)...Done 
Ping:3 (ticks) Testing connection speed to cpan.dagolden.com using pureperl...(10940.00 bytes/s)...Done 
Ping:3 (ticks) Testing connection speed to mirror.sit.wisc.edu using pureperl...(13520.00 bytes/s)...Done 
Three usable mirrors located 
Mirror Check passed for cpan.mirror.clemson.edu (/index.html) 
Bad module name (ultravnc_repeater.pl) detected, skipping it.
```

My host is using Cpanel Accelerated 2.

I have also tried typing an command into the install now area but I get the same error and I have searched google for various answers but nothing has helped as most talk about using ssh which I don't think I have, I am waiting on my hosting company giving me an answer.

Comment: It *sounds* like you are trying to install an (unspecified) Perl script (which should probably be installed by just copying it to the server) by using some kind of third party Perl Module installer (which is designed to pull modules from CPAN and not files from … however you are trying to get the file to it). (Incidentally, I'd consider any hosting service that failed to provide SSH access as "not good enough" for most things)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to add modules from CPAN you can call

```
> sudo cpan install some::module
Enter Password:
```

or

```
> sudo cpan install some/module.pm
Enter Password:
```

Comment: If he's on shared hosting, he won't have superuser access. However, many shared hosting providers (e.g. DreamHost) still allow you to install CPAN modules yourself; you just need to [install them to your home directory](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/CPAN#Setting_up_CPAN).